# How to join strings lists with the same value in a list

Tags: algorithm, list, sorting, flutter, dart

I have a list of a list of strings, and I need to join the values that are the same into a single list and add the different values of each list.

For example:

```
List <String> listA = ["A", "B", "C"];
List <String> listB = ["A", "B", "D"];
List <String> listJ = ["J, K"];
List <String> listz = ["z"];
```

the joined list would be like this:

```
List <String> listJoin = ["A", "B", "C","D"];
```

and the result should be:

```
List <List <String>> resultList = [listJoin, listJ, listz];
```

This is data that comes from a json, maybe I should not use String List.

Any suggestions will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have joined list by:

```
List listJoin = (listA + listB).toSet().toList();
```